# error when running dynamic brownian bridge movement model - small window size

Tags: r, move

I'm trying to run a dynamic brownian bridge movement model on an object of class 'MoveBurst'. I have an individual dataset of 30 locations, and have specified the model as follows:

```
bursted_dbbmm <- brownian.bridge.dyn(bursted, burstType='normal', raster = xAEQD.ind, 
                                       location.error = "LocationError", time.step = 5, ext = 3,
                                       window.size = 29)
```

Running this code returns an error message:

```
Error in brownian.motion.variance.dyn(as(object, ".MoveTrackSingle"),  : 
  window.size can't be larger than the number of locations in the move object
```

This is despite the fact that I specified the window size to be smaller than the number of locations in the move object. No matter what odd value i choose for the window.size, the same error gets returned. Any ideas how to get this to work?

I'm using RStudio v 1.2.5033, and 'move' R package version 3.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the move package. This is now fixed: https://gitlab.com/bartk/move/-/commit/e3db2077a7f0acdb23161a86a8a0d474c85fb41f

Let me know if it now works if you install the development version. It solved it for my reproducible example

Comment: Could you please direct me to the development version website? I updated move to the latest version 4.0.6. as i couldn't find the development version, but it still gives me the same error. so i presume this is not the development version?

Comment: on cran you can find the link to the source (https://bartk.gitlab.io/move/) that is were you can find the development version in gitlab directly. The following commands install it:


require('devtools'); install_git('https://gitlab.com/bartk/move.git')